# How do I set the z-index of a JQuery menu so it slides over the page content?

Tags: jquery, z-index, easing

I have a menu on a page, with a neat easing animation (thanks http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/how-to-make-a-smooth-animated-menu-with-jquery/)

I want the menu to slide over the page content, but at the moment it nudges the text etc out of the way when the menu slides out.

I'm not too hot on z-indexes, but assume this is where I need to be looking, so I tried setting the z-index of the nav div to 10 and the z-index of the content div to 5:

```
 <div id="nav" style="z-index:10">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="green">
                            <p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
                            <p class="subtext">The front page</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="yellow">
                            <p><a href="#">About</a></p>
                            <p class="subtext">More info</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="red">
                            <p><a href="#">Contact</a></p>
                            <p class="subtext">Get in touch</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="blue">
                            <p><a href="#">Submit</a></p>
                            <p class="subtext">Send us your stuff!</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="purple">
                            <p><a href="#">Terms</a></p>
                            <p class="subtext">Legal things</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div style="height: 450px; z-index:5">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
                </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/EyFPB/6/

This didn't work though. How can I make the menu slide over the content without moving it?

Answer (score 0):

D'oh, adding position:absolute to the nav bar styling fixed it.